# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'items' (pandas DataFrame error)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, items

I've created a pandas DataFrame with data from loops (data saved [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v3vIU9upWwtwPNUAFukR9J7hd0Vnh-dD/view?usp=sharing)). Now, I want to iterate over this DataFrame. However, when I try to access the items() function like this:

```
frame = pandas.read_csv(data_path + '/file1.csv')
frame.items()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2668, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'items'
```

This is especially weird since PyCharm offers me the option to fill in `items` if I just type `frame.it`
What does this mean?

Comment: use [`dataframe.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows)

Comment: For me working well.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas

Comment: the `DataFrame` object has no function called `items` if you want to go through the rows you need to use `iterrows()`.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I will use iterrows() and just look at one column. Still weird why there is not items attribute...

Comment: @nidabdella we do have [`dataframe.items()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.items.html#pandas.DataFrame.items) though!

Answer (score 0):

Check your pycharm interpreter. Normally the attribute 'items' works well in Python 3.x but gives the error "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'items'" in Python 2.7.

I also faced the same error until I realized that I was using Python 2.7 instead of Python 3.9 that I intended to use.